# anagram finder using tuples and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples

So I have a program that takes a string, and returns a tuple with all of the letters in the string in sorted order.

The program then needs to create a dictionary, with the tuples as keys, and the values being list of all the words with the keys

So far, I have:

```
_DEBUG = True
def getLetters(string):
    """Purpose, to nab letters from a string and to put them in a tuple in
    sorted order."""
    #sort the letters and put them in a tuple
    tuple_o_letters = tuple(sorted(string))
    if _DEBUG:

    print tuple_o_letters
    return tuple_o_letters
def main():
    try:# open the file
        fin = open("words2.txt")
    except:
        #if file doesn't exist
        print("no, no, file no here.")
        sys.exit(0)
    wordList = [] #create a word list
    for eachline in fin:
        #fill up the word list and get rid of new lines
        wordList.append(eachline.strip())

    word_dict = {} # create a dictionary
    for eachWord in wordList:
        tuple = getLetters(eachWord) # make a tuple out of each word
        word_dict[tuple] = wordList #store it into a dictionary

    print word_dict #print out the dictionary


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Now, while I can store the tuples as dictionary keys, what I can't figure out is how to store the wordlists as values if and only if the word lists have those keys.

For example:
If in the dictionary if have key, ('d', 'o', 'g'), I would get values god and dog for that particular entry, assuming that those two words were in the word lists (which is nabbed from the words2.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the *whole* wordlist. You want to store *just* the matching words for each sorted tuple of letters:

```
word_dict = {} # create a dictionary

for eachWord in wordList:
    key = getLetters(eachWord) # make a tuple out of each word
    if key in word_dict:
        word_dict[key].append(eachWord)
    else:
        word_dict[key] = [eachWord]
```

This creates a list for the given key (letter tuple) if the key is not there yet, otherwise just appends the word.

You can simplify this by using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

word_dict = defaultdict(list)

for eachWord in wordList:
    word_dict[getLetters(eachWord)].append(eachWord)
```

because then you don't need to explicitly test for the key each time.

Comment: I did this code, but it seems to put the execution into an infinite loop.

Comment: @user1768884: Then you need to double-check your code; my example cannot create an infinite loop.